# How to create a tuple of corresponding elements of a 2D numpy array in an efficient way

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 2D numpy arrays, one for latitude, another for longitude.

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3, 4],                  b = [ [a, b, c, d],
      [1, 2, 3, 4],                        [a, b, c, d],
      [1, 2, 3, 4],                        [a, b, c, d],
      [1, 2, 3, 4] ]                       [a, b, c, d] ]
```

I want the following 2 kinds of outputs (a list and a 2D array of tuples)

```
output1 = [ (1,a), (2,a), (3,a), (4,a), (1,b), (2,b), (3,b), (4,b), . . . (3,d), (4,d) ]

output2 = [ [(1,a), (2,a), (3,a), (4,a)],
            [(1,b), (2,b), (3,b), (4,b)],
            [(1,c), (2,c), (3,c), (4,c)],
            [(1,d), (2,d), (3,d), (4,d)] ]
```

How should I do it efficiently without loops?

This is the code for **a** and **b** generation:

```
aa = np.array([1,2,3,4])
bb = np.array(['a','b','c','d'])
a, b = np.meshgrid(aa,bb)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Hint, take a look at `zip`.

Comment: I have tried this **np.array(list(zip(a.ravel(),b.ravel()))).reshape(a.shape)** which gives me error : *cannot reshape array of size 8 into shape (4,)*and **np.dstack((a,b))** which converts it into a 3 dimensional array (which can be taken care of) and each element is converted to string

Comment: Hmm, try `[[*zip(x_, y_)] for x_, y_ in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: I am sorry but it gives : **TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration**

Comment: OK... how about `[[*zip(x_, y_)] for x_, y_ in zip(a.tolist(), b.tolist())]`

Comment: Nops! Tha same error again

Comment: Then that means either "a" is not an array like you claim it is, or you forgot to save your code before running.

Comment: **[[*zip(x_, y_)] for x_, y_ in zip(a, b)]** worked but it gave a list for output2 instead of numpy array and when i converted it to array, its shape changed @cs95

Comment: Mixing datatypes might be doing something funky to you. I think numpy is treating objects differently than single-datatype tensors. Check the shapes and compare with the same-datatype example given. I'm not quite sure and have to run just this moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 arrays:

```
In [88]: aa = np.array([1,2,3,4]) 
    ...: bb = np.array(['a','b','c','d']) 
    ...: a, b = np.meshgrid(aa,bb)                                                   
In [89]: a                                                                           
Out[89]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
In [90]: b                                                                           
Out[90]: 
array([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
       ['d', 'd', 'd', 'd']], dtype='<U1')
```

Some version of `concatenate` can be used to join the two arrays.  `stack` with axis 2 does it, so does `np.array((a,b))` followed by a transpose.

```
In [91]: np.stack((a,b),axis=2)                                                      
Out[91]: 
array([[['1', 'a'],
        ['2', 'a'],
        ['3', 'a'],
        ['4', 'a']],

       [['1', 'b'],
        ['2', 'b'],
        ['3', 'b'],
        ['4', 'b']],

       [['1', 'c'],
        ['2', 'c'],
        ['3', 'c'],
        ['4', 'c']],

       [['1', 'd'],
        ['2', 'd'],
        ['3', 'd'],
        ['4', 'd']]], dtype='<U21')
```

But the combined array is string dtype, not a mix of integers and strings.  And not tuples.  It's a (4,4,2) array.

But if we convert the arrays to object dtype:

```
In [93]: np.stack((a.astype(object),b.astype(object)),axis=2)                        
Out[93]: 
array([[[1, 'a'],
        [2, 'a'],
        [3, 'a'],
        [4, 'a']],

       [[1, 'b'],
        [2, 'b'],
       ...
        [4, 'd']]], dtype=object)
```

We can reshape it to (-1,2) and then `tolist()` to produce the list version.

Or we could make a structured array, with a integer field and string field.  Its print display uses tuples, to mark the inner records (which are distinct from the last size 2 dimension above).

```
In [98]: arr = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype='int,U5')                                     
In [99]: arr                                                                         
Out[99]: 
array([[(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')],
       [(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')],
       [(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')],
       [(0, ''), (0, ''), (0, ''), (0, '')]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U5')])
In [100]: arr['f0']=a                                                                
In [101]: arr['f1']=b                                                                
In [102]: arr                                                                        
Out[102]: 
array([[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')],
       [(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')],
       [(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c')],
       [(1, 'd'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd')]],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i8'), ('f1', '<U5')])

In [103]: print(arr)                                                                 
[[(1, 'a') (2, 'a') (3, 'a') (4, 'a')]
 [(1, 'b') (2, 'b') (3, 'b') (4, 'b')]
 [(1, 'c') (2, 'c') (3, 'c') (4, 'c')]
 [(1, 'd') (2, 'd') (3, 'd') (4, 'd')]]
```

`zip` list comprehension does the list version nicely:

```
In [105]: [item for item in zip(a.flat,b.flat)]                                      
Out[105]: 
[(1, 'a'),
 (2, 'a'),
 (3, 'a'),
 (4, 'a'),
 (1, 'b'),
 ...
 (4, 'd')]
```

For this sample size, the list comprehension is faster.  Trying to avoid loops isn't always the most efficient way.

===

Elements of `arr` are `np.void` objects, though they display as tuples.  To get actual tuples we have to convert to list or object dtype:

```
In [109]: arr.tolist()                                                               
Out[109]: 
[[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')],
 [(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')],
 [(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c')],
 [(1, 'd'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd')]]
In [110]: arr.astype(object)                                                         
Out[110]: 
array([[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'a')],
       [(1, 'b'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'b')],
       [(1, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'c')],
       [(1, 'd'), (2, 'd'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'd')]], dtype=object)
In [111]: type(_[0,0])                                                               
Out[111]: tuple
```

The fields of the structured array can be accessed by name:

```
In [112]: arr['f0']                                                                  
Out[112]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The LAST ONE worked for me. But can you please explain why the individual tuples' datatype is shown as void instead of tuple?

Comment: With a `structured` array like this the elements, or records, are compound objects, with this `void` type.  They display as tuples, but aren't actually tuples.  However a `tolist()` will convert them to tuples.  We could create an object dtype array that contains tuples,

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Although, this void nature is giving me great complications when I am writing these to pandas dataframes

Answer (score 2):

solution without numpy

```
from itertools import chain
output2 = [list(zip(i,j)) for i,j in zip(a,zip(*b))]
output1 = list(chain.from_iterable(output2))
```

Comment: Same Error: **TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration**

Comment: Yup, it works fine for me. Set `a = np.array(a)` Neerav, same for b.

Comment: It works for output1 but for output2, it changes the shape to 3D arrays

Comment: @NeeravKaushal your input / code you provided doesn't give full view of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am sorry if its not clear but i have posted everything. I have two arrays **aa**, **bb** which are normal 1D numpy arrays. I have created a grid from them using numpy meshgrid. The outputs are in **a** and **b** (which are now 2D numpy arrays). Now i just want the outputs posted. I have got output1 from your code successfully but not output2

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized approach using numpy and `tolist`:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4],
              [1,2,3,4]])
b = np.array([[10,20,30,40],
              [10,20,30,40],
              [10,20,30,40],
              [10,20,30,40]])

x = np.stack((a,b), axis=-1)

x.reshape(4,4,2).tolist()
[[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10]], 
 [[1, 20], [2, 20], [3, 20], [4, 20]], 
 [[1, 30], [2, 30], [3, 30], [4, 30]], 
 [[1, 40], [2, 40], [3, 40], [4, 40]]]

x.reshape(16,2).tolist()
[[1, 10], [2, 10], [3, 10], [4, 10], [1, 20], [2, 20], [3, 20], [4, 20], [1, 30], [2, 30], [3, 30], [4, 30], [1, 40], [2, 40], [3, 40], [4, 40]]
```

Comment: It alters the shape of the output completely

Comment: Should be fixed now, let me know if I missed something.

Comment: It worked this time but each value is converted to string. @David Parks